# wcf net.tcp Per Session problem - self-hosing

Tags: wcf, self-hosting, nettcpbinding

I have problem sometime wcf self hosting using net.tcp binding Receive Data from Client but Not Response To Client where data Not Return and Hang. what is problem?

Comment: You must add more details and some code snippet. is your server code can hang ? if yes the client will be hanged until the receive timeout

Comment: yep Wael, post some code and we'll be happy to try to help

Comment: I would like you could post more details about your project and the error.

Comment: when change domain it work and after one day the previous domain work. i think it is block of return , i don't know it is by country or not because my application work for one year without any problems. i use newtonjson.dll to serialization before return data and the data is class inside it classes and datatables